# How do you set fixed NS values on Google Cloud DNS?

Tags: google-app-engine, dns, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am trying to manage my domain through Cloud DNS from Google Cloud Platform:

On Google Cloud Platform, when I create a new zone for my domain, I get something like this: 
[image]

Then I will proceed to namecheap to enter these values as my custom DNS server:

[image]

I've done this a few times and I realize Google Cloud actually rotates between

- `ns-cloud-aX.googledomains.com`,
- `ns-cloud-bX.googledomains.com`,
- `ns-cloud-cX.googledomains.com`
- and `ns-cloud-dX.googledomains.com`

whenever you create your own zone for your domain. *(where X is a number from 1-4)*

I am interested to create a managed zone with NS records that are always `ns-cloud-aX.googledomains.com`. This is because I am switching to a new registrar which requires me to manually set the these values per domain.

I tried changing the NS values in Google Cloud but I keep seeing this error:

[image]

**Is it possible to manually set my NS records to always use `ns-cloud-aX.googledomains.com`?**

Comment: Have you managed to resolve your issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not changing it as [Google Cloud will automatically give you an NS record, depending on your zone](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/quickstart#create_a_managed_public_zone). This would/might cause some errors.

Comment: Creating multiple zones identically (apart from the name) within the same project may yield different NS servers, so I'm not sure where you're going with this.

Answer (score -3):

[first step is to add Cloud DNS
 CREATE ZONE
zone name you recored](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9C2He.jpg)

then you HAVE TO create Load balancing